# I need a regular expression to substitute pseudo html in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have texts like this one:

```
this is a text in [lang lang="en" ]english[/lang] or a text in [lang lang="en" ]spanish[/lang]
```

I need to substitute them for:

```
this is a text in <span lang="en">english </span> or a text in <span lang="es">spanish</span>
```

I need a regular expression, not a simple replace. The languages in the lang tag can be whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply replace `[/lang]` with `</span>` and use

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"\[lang lang=""(\w+)""\]", "<span lang=\"$1\">")
```

to replace the opening tag.

Comment: Thx.The final solution has been:
     string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\[lang lang=(.*)\](.*?)\[/lang\]", "<span lang=$1>$2</span>");
I haven't found the way to escape \" inside this regex, don't know.

Comment: @netadictos: My mistake, sorry. In verbatim strings quotes are escaped with more quotes, not backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
\[lang lang="([^"]*)" \](.*?)\[/lang\]
```

Replacement:

```
<span lang="$1">$2 </span>
```

Comment: The space at the ending looks weird.

     \[lang lang=\"([^\"]*)\"\s*\](.*?)\[/lang\]